# Center a small line under text

Tags: html, css

I wanted to have a line under my text, but not underline it completely. A line smaller than the text and centered just below.
My text is inside a div and aligned right, and if i move the line to the right i can center it under the text but the problem is that the text can have different sizes.

[Here are some things i have tried](http://codepen.io/KatT84/pen/eifIu)

What i need is something like this:

```
      menu
       _
  longmenu
      _
     menus
       _
```

Hope some one can help.

Comment: You could use Javascript to calculate the width of the text and place an image accordingly, but that seems messy. Can you explain the larger goal so that we can provide alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you had the CSS3 tag, here is a CSS3 option taken from your example:

```css
.text{
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
    
.text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  left: 35%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="text">test 2 small</p>
  <p class="text">test test 2 large</p>
  <p class="text">test 2 small</p>
  <p class="text">test test 2 large</p>
</div>
```

Or if you prefer a fixed-width line:

```
.text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: this is great. can i know how to responsive this line ? because when i reducing the size the line won't responsive

Comment: The percentage-based solution is already completely responsive. You'll have to explain what problem you're having with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your text in a `<span>`. The `<span>` will be as width as the text.
Then you make a small line in Photoshop or something and place that on the background.

HTML:

```
<span class="underlined">text</span>
```

CSS:

```
.underlined {
     background: url(line.gif) center bottom no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML and CSS to achieve the effect:

HTML:

```
<span id="example">menu</span>
```

CSS:

```
example {
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

example:hover {
    background: url(line1x50.gif) repeat-x 100% 100%;
    }
```

You can define the image width and it will be the size you want.

Comment: This would require that the OP give up the right-alignment that he/she specifically mentioned.